# GCP Cloud Functions - Go - goroutine HTTPS TLS handshake timeout

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to utilise goroutines in a golang GCP Cloud function and receive different results with and without the goroutine for idential code.

I am calling a function, 'Instance()', which makes an HTTPS GET request.  If the function is called without a goroutine everything works as expected.  If the function is called with a goroutine, 'go Instance()', I get a 'TLS handshake timeout' for the identical call.

I presume there is an issue with TLS and concurrency but cannot find any information.

```
func GoRoutineTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    defaultRoundTripper := http.DefaultTransport
    defaultTransportPointer, ok := defaultRoundTripper.(*http.Transport)

    if !ok {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("defaultRoundTripper not an *http.Transport"))
    }

    defaultTransport := *defaultTransportPointer // dereference it to get a copy of the struct that the pointer points to
    defaultTransport.TLSHandshakeTimeout = 10 * time.Second
    defaultTransport.MaxIdleConns = 100
    defaultTransport.MaxIdleConnsPerHost = 100

    client = &http.Client{Transport: &defaultTransport}

    for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
            Instance()        /* This works as expected */
            go Instance()     /* This fails with 'TLS handshake timeout' */
    }
}


func Instance( ) {

    resp, err := client.Get("https://google.com")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        defer resp.Body.Close()

        if resp.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
            bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }

        fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)

        bodyString := string(bodyBytes)
        fmt.Println(bodyString)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On Cloud Functions, when the response terminates, the request may terminate. `Instance()` runs sync, so it's part of the request. `go Instance()`  schedules something to run, but then control flow continues. The function may exit before the routine is finished processing.

Comment: To verify this, you could use a sync.WaitGroup to wait for the goroutines to finish outside the for loop